# Solution to an equation modulo p

Tags: number-theory

Find the number of roots of $x^2+x-1$ modulo $p^2$ for an arbitrary prime p,i.e., the cardinality of $\{n|1\le n\le p^2$ and $n^2+n+1$ is divisible by $p^2\}$

MY approach is Let $a$ be the root of $x^2+x-1$ modulo p then n is of the form $n=kp+a$ for some k between 0 and p-1. We need to find the value of k such that, kp+a is root of the equation

$(kp+a)^2+(kp+a)-1$ modulo $p^2$

Now, this leads to $(2a+1)kp+a^2+a-1$ modulo $p^2$

Now, I am stuck here. Please help?

Comment: Solve the mod $p$ congruence first, please. It should be doable with a combination of the quadratic formula and quadratic reciprocity.

Comment: You may also prefer the term “completing the square” to the quadratic formula.

Comment: I can't figure very well how to continue your approach, but I can answer with another one if you are interested.